# Check if URL is from a certain website

Tags: php, regex, url

#### Problem

The user can submit a form where he can submit a link to `sitea.com`. Now what I want to do is check if the user actually submitted an URL coming from `sitea.com`

#### What I've tried

I've tried to check if the URL is correct (using regex), and contains `sitea.com`. But that contains gaps, as anyone can add `?haha=sitea.com` to an URL and still have a match. And 'cause I'm no master in regex, my "solution" ends here.

#### My question

Is it possible to check if `$_POST['url']` is actually a link to `sitea.com`?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the form input contains `sitea.com`? Or something else? Please clarify

Comment: @AmalMurali Exactly, a form wich the user submits, where he can copy/paste a URL that I require to be from `sitea.com`.

Comment: curl() check the headers

Comment: Could the people voting this down explain why?

Comment: @Thew: I didn't vote it down, but I think that's because your question isn't very clear. `Is it possible to check if $_POST['url'] is actually and URL coming from sitea.com` -- this sentence is confusing. Perhaps, you could edit the question and clarify?

Comment: @AmalMurali Wow, did I realy write that? Sorry for the horrible grammar, edited my question.

Comment: @Thew: not everyone speaks English as their first language and it's okay to make mistakes! Also see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

Comment: I wish I could -1 the downvoters ! This question helped me a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's best [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) here. Regex may work, but it's best to avoid using regex when a built-in function is available.

I'd do something like:

```
$url = '...';
$domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));

if ($domain == 'sitea.com') {
    # code...
}
```

As a function:

```
function getDomain($url) 
{
    $domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
    if ($domain == 'sitea.com') {
        return True;
    } else {
        return False;
    }

}
```

Test cases:

```
var_dump(getDomain('http://sitea.com/'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://sitea.com/directory'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://subdomain.sitea.com/'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://sub.subdomain.sitea.com/#test'));

var_dump(getDomain('http://subdomain.notsitea.com/#dsdf'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://sitea.somesite.com'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://example.com/sitea.com'));
var_dump(getDomain('http://sitea.example.com/test.php?haha=sitea.com'));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)

bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

### [Demo!](http://codepad.org/PU6D0kOK)

Answer (score 3):

**This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: Yup, this is working. Matching hostname with `sitea.com` and or `www.sitea.com` works correctly.