# Check if URL entered is from a certain domain

Tags: php

I have a field where a user can enter a URL. I need to check if that URL is from a certain domain, in this case `google.com`.

I've tried this, however, it doesn't work for all cases (which I list below):

```
if(strstr(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST), 'google.com') { // continue }
```

- http://www.google.com/blah - works
- https://www.google.com/blah - works
- google.com/blah - doesn't work
- www.google.com/blah - doesn't work

Is there a way to do this without regex? If not, how would it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: `parse_url()` requires a valid URL. If it doesn't have the scheme (ie the `http://` bit) then it's not a valid URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) requires a valid URL and `google.com/blah` isn't valid (as of [PHP 5.3.3](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)) -- so it won't work. As a work around, you can append the `http` if doesn't exist already, and then check the domain.

Use the following function:

```
function checkRootDomain($url) 
{
    if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
        $url = "http://" . $url;
    }

    $domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
    if ($domain == 'google.com') {
        return True;
    } else {
        return False;
    }

}
```

Test cases:

```
var_dump(checkRootDomain('http://www.google.com/blah'));
var_dump(checkRootDomain('https://www.google.com/blah '));
var_dump(checkRootDomain('google.com/blah'));
var_dump(checkRootDomain('www.google.com/blah '));
```

Result:

```
bool(true) 
bool(true) 
bool(true) 
bool(true)
```

It is a modified version of my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678070/check-if-url-is-from-a-certain-website/18678205#18678205).

Hope this helps!

Comment: To check if it returned true, I would just do `if(checkRootDomain('google.com/blah')) { // true } else { //false }`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in php prior to version 5.4.7: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

> Version 5.4.7  Fixed host recognition when scheme is omitted and a leading component separator is present.
>
> <?php
> $url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';
>
> // Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
> var_dump(parse_url($url));
> ?>

Your options are to upgrade to php >=5.4.7, or to detect a missing `http:` and add it if it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_url()` requires a valid URL. If it doesn't have the scheme (ie the http:// bit) then it's not a valid URL.

You can add a scheme very easily, though. Just check whether the string contains a colon (`:`), and if not, add `http://` to the front of it:

```
if(strpos($link, ':')===false) {$link = "http://".$link;}
```

Now your `parse_url()` call should work a bit better.